# Is it possible to choose some elements from the set such that there average is exactly $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose we are given a set $S$, which contains some numbers. We are also given a number $x$. We want to choose some elements from the set so that their average is exactly equal to $x$. We need to check if this some can be made or not. Now here I can see that I can pick two elements from the set some number of times to create a sum. Let's say we pick a number $a$ times and another number $b$ times. We can alter the number of times we take two numbers and create a different average or increase or decrease the average. But I am not able to see how can we make the average exactly $x$. And how do we check if it is possible in the first place?

Edit : The average, which we want to make, is an integer value. Basically any value of average between maximum and minimum value of the set can be made. I am looking for an mathematical/intuitive proof that any value between maximum and minimum value can be made. It is easy to see that we can increase or decrease the average by taking different values different number of times. But how do we guarantee for an average $x$.

Comment: If $x=\sqrt{2}$ and $S=\{3,4\}$ then there is no solution to $3a+4b = x$, with $a$ and $b$ being integers.

Comment: It looks like a problem of programming. I suggest you to clarify the source of the problem.

Comment: Yes this is a programming question but I am looking for a mathematical proof.

Comment: So I assume $S$ is a finite set. Mathematicians often satisfy just by the statement 'if the candidate is finite, try all'.

Comment: Just to check: You can use an element of the set as many times as you like for making the average?

Comment: Are the "numbers" of $S$ integers?

Comment: @paw88789 Yes the numbers are integers and the average to be made is also integer.

Comment: @aerile Yes the set is of finite numbers but we can use the elements of the set as many times as we want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $p$ is the minimum value of $S$ and $q$ is the maximum value of $S$. If we are given a target average $t$ with $p\le t\le q$. (Here $p,q,t$ are all integers.) Then if you take $q-t$ copies of $p$ and $t-p$ copies of $q$, you will get an average of $t$.